# Modify a nested dict field based on keys provided

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've three different documents as follows

```
{
  "category" : "aaaaa",
  "summary" : {
    "details" : {
      "city" : "abc"
      "year_of_reg" : "2012",
      "dept" : "dev"
    }
  }
}

{
  "category" : "bbbb",
  "summary" : {
    "details" : {
      "city" : "abc",
      "year_of_reg" : "2016",
      "dept" : "dev"
    }
  }
}

{
  "category" : "aaaaa",
  "summary" : {
    "details" : {
      "dept" : "ui",
      "year_of_reg" : "2018"
    }
  }
}
```

I'll provide a array of required keys and the details under summary should only have those required keys. Remaining keys should be popped

For Eg. If I provided city and year_of_reg as required keys, the three documents should be modified as follows

```
{
  "category" : "aaaaa",
  "summary" : {
    "details" : {
      "city" : "abc"
      "year_of_reg" : "2012"
    }
  }
}

{
  "category" : "bbbb",
  "summary" : {
    "details" : {
      "city" : "abc",
      "year_of_reg" : "2016"
    }
  }
}

{
  "category" : "aaaaa",
  "summary" : {
    "details" : {
      "year_of_reg" : "2018"
    }
  }
}
```

How this can be achieved?

Comment: `[SO_CodeSnippet].includes(triedCode) = false` :(

Comment: Try using a projection which only include fields that you want returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
const values = [ "city", "year_of_reg" ];

db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "summary.details": {
            $arrayToObject: { // transform modified array back to subdocument
                $filter: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$summary.details" }, // transform "summary.details" into a key-value pair representation
                    as: "this",
                    cond: {
                        $in: [ "$$this.k", values] // only keep the key-value pairs where the key is one of the strings you provide in the array
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```